# Java - refering to an object

Tags: java, arrays, oop, object, arraylist

I'm new in Java and I'm trying to create a social network. I have a array of objects "People" which their names, e-mails and so on. I would like to create relations between them (like 'friends') so that program would connect two object.

I though about doing another array inside of every "Person" object, so each person would have a name, e-mail and friend array with all friends inside of it. I don't know how to refer to an other object of type People inside of object of this type.

I don't know if it's clear..
Hope it is!
Thank You in advance!

Comment: For starters, use `List<>`, not array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private List<Person> friends;

    // Leave the rest for you.

    public void addFriend(Person p) { 
        if (p != null) {
            this.friends.add(p);
        }
    }

    public void removeFriend(Person p) {
        this.friends.remove(p);
    }

    public boolean isFriend(Person p) { 
        return this.friends.contains(p);
    }
}
```

You'll want constructors and a way to add and remove `Person` from your friend `List`.

Comment: Ok, I got that, but how to write that Person[1].friend is a Person[2]? Because I have this in 2 separate classes Person and SocialNetwork, so each Person is an another object of SocialNetwork, but when I try to set a friend of some person I would have to (?) use other object of SocialNetwork inside of Person class...

Comment: Implementation suggested by @duffymo is good. That is how you can represent a Person and his/her friends. Your social network simplistically is **nothing but a bunch of person objects**, and each person object contains references to a bunch of other people as their friends. When you try to set A to be a friend of B, you just do B.addFriend(A). You really don't need to manage that in the SocialNetwork class.

Comment: I'd do it this way: for a given Person, iterate over their List of Person friends.  Then ask that friend "Is this Person on your friend List?"  If it contains this, then they are mutual friends.  Provide an API that makes it easy to do.